# Preprocessor ifdef does not hide the code blocks in an Objective C framework

Tags: xcode, preprocessor-directive, objective-c-framework

I am working on an Objective C framework and we want to hide some debug related methods in our release version. I thought using #ifdef DEBUG can easily server for that purpose, so put the debug related method in a #ifdef block:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
+(void)unregisterDevice OBJC_VISIBLE;
#endif
```

The above code block shows up exactly, in the aggregated framework when I build it with either of our Debug, or Release targets! I thought, the compiler would remove #ifdef and #endif when DEBUG is defined and will hide the whole block when DEBUG is not defined. Would you please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Show how you're setting your Debug and Release compiler flags.

Comment: Target > Build Settings > Apple Clang Preprocessor > Preprocessor Macros > Configuration > DEBUG=1 (for our Debug configuration). The Release configuration doesn't have the DEBUG macro.

Comment: What do you mean "shows up exactly, in the aggregated framework when I build it"? Are you looking at a header file that got copied into the framework headers? Nothing will actually modify the headers as they're copied. They will always be copied verbatim.

Comment: I meant you would see the exact block of code including #ifdef Debug there. Is there any way to hide that method declaration in the header file?

Comment: No, preprocessor directives don't modify header files, they only modify what input the compiler sees to generate the binary.